# Correct translation of Norwegian landcover classes derived from WMS?

Tags: land-cover, land-classification, land-use, norway

I am making a map of the study site located in Norway. I have accessed the awesome and free WMS data regarding landcover (I guess: N250 Arealdekkeflate) https://openwms.statkart.no/skwms1/wms.topo4.graatone?

I have made a map and added a WMS legend, but, the legend is in norwagian, of course. Please, where can i find the correct terms in English? I think my confusion originates from the the difference between land cover and land use, as well as different levels of aggregation of landcover classes by spatial scale representation. **The terminology is very field-dependent and therefore simple translation by any dictionary just gives a general idea, but not the exact scientific term.**

Please, what do you think about my translations? Can you suggest me a better guide?

[image]

Comment: Why not to asking this question on [Linguistics Beta SE](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Hi @Taras, than you for suggestion, I will try to post it there as well. But, I think that correctness between Norwegian and English terms in land cover use will be more familiar to the specialized GIS users than to the more generally oriented linguists.

Comment: Well @Taras, they just kicked me out of Linguistics Beta SE.. as " this site is about Linguistics, the scientific study of language. Requests for translation or proofreading is off-topic here"

Comment: Why not [contact the service providers](https://openwms.statkart.no/skwms1/wms.topo4.graatone?service=WMS&request=GetCapabilities&), English is widely spoken in Norway

Comment: "Bymessig bebyggelse" means city-like built-up area and "tettbebyggelse" means village-like residential areas. The classification is about land use and thus "industri" stands for industrial area, not only for buildings. "Dagbrutt" means an open cast mine and "steintipp" is indeed rocks, on the top of the fjells.